# How to bend a 3D scanned tubular object without altering its diameter?

Tags: distort

I am creating an insert/shim (something like a [last](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last) for shoemakers), namely a stiff 3D-printed part designed to permanently distend a plastic tracheostomy tube's [inner cannula](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pl0d03e9q8d4ixl/SampleInnerTracheostomyCannulaBareAndInsertedIntoOuterCannula.jpg?dl=0). This inner cannula has an inside diameter of 5.5 mm.

Here is the unbent inner cannula insert:

[image: Unbent inner cannula insert]

Here is the bend plan for this object:
[image: Sample bend plan]

I want the inner cannula to take on a different shape, namely when held with the open flared top facing me and the tube curving away and down from me, I want an additional 10 degrees of front-to-back tilt (so the distal end comes towards me) and 28 degrees of left-leaning tilt ([distending](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dhsrc1sxj2ymlhr/ProposedTracheostomyInnerCannulaDistension.png?dl=0) the tube in two dimensions).

I have been experimenting with Blender's simple distortion tools, but I'm finding that the distorted 3D figure becomes flatter.  I need to constrain the distortion so that the diameter of the tube remains intact throughout the whole bending process (I intend to place the plastic tube in hot water and soften the plastic enough to allow it to be permanently distended and shaped to the ideal shape that I require).

I took a 3D scan of the outside of the inner cannula and then used 3D Slicer's Margin tool to reduce the diameter evenly by enough to ensure there will be a 0.25mm gap between the outer wall of the insert and the inner wall of the inner cannula.  I hope this will be enough to allow me to slip it inside gradually as I distend it.  The challenge is that this kind of plastic cracks if it is distended too quickly, so this is very much a work in progress.

Does anybody know how I would use Blender to achieve this complex bend?  This is a medical application for my special needs 16-year-old son.

Hint : I'm a Python programmer so if the solution is complex I'm up to the task, I just need a pointer in the right direction.

Here's a [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sda1ihw3hel9lll/FrontBackAngledInnerCannula_filled.obj?dl=0) to an OBJ file of the unbent insert.  The side of the tube that is sharper and noncylindrical is the top.  The top third of the object must not be distended, the bending needs to be kept to the bottom 2/3 of the tube.

Here's a picture

Power to the people !  Blender rocks !

Comment: hello could you please show some pictures, it would help to visualize

Comment: Look more carefully, I already have links to applicable pictures.

Comment: it's better to directly show them in your message   ;)

Comment: @ Myles Dear so from what I understand you basically need to 3D print a shape in order to bend another one, have you tried to bend the object with a curve modifier?

Comment: I managed to hire a developer to take care of this for me.  Check him out!  https://www.upwork.com/freelancers/tadsouza  .  Check out our final product :  https://opensea.io/assets/0x495f947276749ce646f68ac8c248420045cb7b5e/62747652541663514507087434811839774222596193624949302758567741995891971588097/

Comment: Nice, so did you 3D print it?